# Does the standard AmazonDynamoDBClient use exponential back off when retrying requests that failed due to a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, exponential-backoff

I've created a standard `AmazonDynamoDBClient` using the `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder`:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
```

In the [documentation for the AmazonDynamoDBClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html), it mentions:

> `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` - Your request rate is too
>   high. The AWS SDKs for DynamoDB automatically retry requests that
>   receive this exception. Your request is eventually successful, unless
>   your retry queue is too large to finish. Reduce the frequency of
>   requests and use exponential backoff.

Is exponential backoff used by default for standard clients when retrying requests that failed to due to a `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`? Or is this something I will need to manually configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS documentation for [Error Retries and Exponential Backoff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.RetryAndBackoff) mentions this:

> The AWS SDKs implement automatic retry logic and exponential backoff.

The default DynamoDB Retry strategy for Java can be found in the source code: [PredefinedRetryPolicies.java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/retry/PredefinedRetryPolicies.java)